# how to extend odoo ShowPaymentLineWidget.js

Tags: javascript, python

I am new in odoo v10/js coding,I really need your help of how to extend the ShowPaymentLineWidget.js in odoo. I override the _get_payment_info_JSON in account_invoice.py, _get_move_vals in account_payment.py and account_payment.xml to add **new fields**.

I know I need to add my fields in:

```js
 _.each(this.$('.js_payment_info'), function(k, v){
                var options = {
                    'content': QWeb.render('PaymentPopOver', {
                            'name': info.content[v].name, 
                            'journal_name': info.content[v].journal_name, 
                            'date': info.content[v].date,
                            'amount': info.content[v].amount,
                            'currency': info.content[v].currency,
                            'position': info.content[v].position,
                            'payment_id': info.content[v].payment_id,
                            'move_id': info.content[v].move_id,
                            'ref': info.content[v].ref,
                            'new_field': info.content[v].new_field,

                            }),
                    'html': true,
                    'placement': 'left',
                    'title': _t('Payment Information'),
                    'trigger': 'focus',
                    'delay': { "show": 0, "hide": 100 },
                };
```

I already refer with this link:https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-inherit-javascript-class-widget-odoo-v9-108051 but still no luck.

Can anyone provide me some example? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you put your whole code ?

Comment: @KevalMehta, thank you for noticing of my concern. Based on my post above I only added **new_field** following with this reference: https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-add-details-in-information-tab-pament-widget-in-odoo-10-119992. My problem is, I do not know how to inherit the account_payment_widget.js and extend the ShowPaymentLineWidget to get the info.content value of **new_field** ... can you give me some idea of how to do it...? :-)